# MySQL: Curdate() vs Now()

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

What is difference between MySQL `Curdate()` and `Now()`?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

For questions like this, it is always worth taking a look in the manual first. [Date and time functions in the mySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

`CURDATE()` returns the DATE part of the current time. [Manual on CURDATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

`NOW()` returns the date and time portions as a timestamp in various formats, depending on how it was requested. [Manual on NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).

Answer (score 85):

Just for the fun of it:

```
CURDATE() = DATE(NOW())
```

Or

```
NOW() = CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', CURTIME())
```

Answer (score 46):

`CURDATE()` will give current date while `NOW()` will give full date time.

Run the queries, and you will find out whats the difference between them.

```
SELECT NOW();     -- You will get 2010-12-09 17:10:18
SELECT CURDATE(); -- You will get 2010-12-09
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually MySQL provide a lot of easy to use function in daily life without more effort from user side-

**NOW()**  it produce date and time both in current scenario whereas
**CURDATE()**  produce date only, **CURTIME()** display time only, we can use one of them according to our need with **CAST** or merge other calculation it, MySQL rich in these type of function.

**NOTE:-** *You can see the difference using query select NOW() as NOWDATETIME, CURDATE() as NOWDATE, CURTIME() as NOWTIME ;*