# php code for checking current date is newer than date in database

Tags: php, mysql, web

iam developing a webSite using php and mysql and am really beginner  in this area.. Now iam stuck in a place where i have to check the current date is newer than the date in my database

so i have written a code like this but it's not working

```
$SQL = "UPDATE adverts SET active='0' WHERE enddate<NOW()";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$SQL);
```

in the above code 'advert' is my table name and 'enddate' is where the column containing date in database

can anybody please help me?

Comment: does it work if you run it straight on the db?

Comment: Why don't you obtain the data, and then compare it with your application?

Comment: @Anthony please see the second line...I have run it in db

Comment: @AmalMurali there is no error in my program... it's not giving the output that i expected

Comment: `NOW()` will return something that looks like this: *10/6/2013 6:46:57 AM* so unless the data you are storing is exactly the same it wont work, and you appear to only be using date. Try using `CURDATE()` or convert your date storage to UNIX

Comment: What is the type of enddate? Sample data, and what you receive as result. Also what is the expected result?

Comment: @user1672694 - this is not correct and it is much better to use date types for dates. `NOW()` is a mysql function not a php function

Comment: @Anthony What is not correct? Of course it is an SQL function. I don't think you know what you are talking about

Comment: @user1672694 - "so unless the data you are storing is exactly the same it wont work" ... This is incorrect and you should chill out.

Comment: @Anthony In my experience it hasn't and you should probably take a leaf out of your own book before making yourself a hypocrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Anthony described in comments, it's a good idea to check if your query is working in `PHPMyAdmin` at all, by going to `PHPMyAdmin` -> `SQL` -> `Run Query`. This way you can distinguish if it's an *MySQL Error* or an *PHP Error*.

```
 UPDATE adverts SET active = 0 WHERE ( enddate < NOW() )
```

I've set active '0' to 0, simply because I believe it'll be an `Integer` field - secondly, there's a small but important difference in your `enddate`:

is it a `date` field or a `datetime` field? See below:

```
SELECT NOW(); // You will get 2010-12-09 17:10:18
SELECT CURDATE(); // You will get 2010-12-09
```

Source: [MySQL Curdate() vs now()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397755/mysql-curdate-vs-now)

You can use `affected_rows()` to see if you query did work, but just didn't meet any criteria

```
$sql = "UPDATE adverts SET active = 0 WHERE ( enddate < NOW() )";
$queried = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );
if ( mysqli_affected_rows( $con ) >= 1 ) {
     //We know some rows were effected.
}
```

Comment: hi,i have run the query in databse and its working... but why it's not working with php

Comment: [Run any PHP errors](http://www.mjdigital.co.uk/blog/php-display-errors-at-runtime/), I doubt there will be any, because nothing is 'failing' but I think it's going to be something to do with enddate being a date field, not datetime.

Comment: What exactly you expect of this code to work? Just to update table, or you want to get updated rows in $result ?

Comment: Also @MilanZavišić pointed out an important point, is it adverts or advert?

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried

```
UPDATE adverts SET active='0' WHERE enddate<DATE(NOW())
```

also, is it adverts or advert?

Or you can try with CURDATE()

```
UPDATE adverts SET active='0' WHERE enddate<CURDATE()
```