# Curdate() Vs current_date MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-date-functions

What is the difference between `curdate()` and `current_date` in MySQL?

Comment: try to search for the answer yourself first....its very simple question

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAnsari has it occurred to you that StackOverflow is a knowledgebase? Do you think this website should be reserved exclusively for the most complicated questions?

Answer (score 26):

There's no difference. It says it right there in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date):

> CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_DATE() are synonyms for CURDATE().

Answer (score 4):

Please refer the documentation 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

curdate() and current_date() are synonymous.

However for your information there is a difference between
curdate() and now()

Question: [MySQL: Curdate() vs Now()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397755/mysql-curdate-vs-now)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, they are synonyms (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)).