# How to insert values of variables using python 2.7 into mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I want to insert the value of variable (temp, hum) into my table sensors using mysql database (db name:project). I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and the connection is made between python and MySQL, but I can't put the value of the variable. So any help is welcome, and thanks.

This is my script Python:

```
from random import *
import socket
import sys
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime

temp = randrange(10, 31, 2)
hum = randrange(300, 701, 2)

print temp
print hum

conn=mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='12345',host='localhost',database='projet');
mycursor=conn.cursor();
mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO sensors VALUES('$datetime','$temp','$hum')""");
conn.commit()
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM sensors")
```

This is my table where you can find the variables temp and hum and not their values:

[image: This is my table where you can find the variables temp and hum and not their values]

Comment: **WARNING**: Please be careful to [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/python.html) those values. Inserting data directly is really dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are not passing the variable values into the query. Pass them with the query into the `execute()` method:

```
mycursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO 
        sensors 
    VALUES
        ('$datetime', %s, %s)""", (temp, hum))
```

where `%s` are placeholders for the query parameters. Note that the database driver would handle the parameter type conversion and escaping automatically.

As for the `$datetime`, if you want to have a current date/datetime in this column, look into using `NOW()` or `CURDATE()`, see:

- [MySQL: Curdate() vs Now()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397755/mysql-curdate-vs-now)

Answer (score 0):

> but i can't put the value of variable

Assuming data-time is a string and the rest are integers

Try

```
"INSERT INTO sensors VALUES('%s','%d','%d')", %(date, temp, num)
```

in the `execute` method

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is valid?