# Update date column to current date

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-workbench

i have created a column for date using workbench now i have to update all the values of that column to current date either using sql query or using python code

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", 
password="afif123", db="library")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
fill = '''UPDATE issued_book SET Today = current_date()'''
mycursor.execute(fill)
#or
today = datetime.datetime.now()
fill = '''UPDATE issued_book SET Today = %s'''
mycursor.execute(fill, [today])
```

any of above two attempt doesn't helping

i have kept datatype of date column as DATETIME()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [do it in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397755/mysql-curdate-vs-now), just modify your first query a bit...

```
update issued_book set today = now()
```

instead of current_date(), which is not a mysql function.